# I dont know why my python code isnt working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to this, so I have no idea why this is wrong. Please help.

Thanks if you help.

```
print("%s is a very %s person. They usually spend all their time %s.") % input("Please enter a name: "), input("Please enter an adjective: "), input("Please eneter an ing verb: ")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\firstthingy.py", line 1, in <module>
    print("%s is a very %s person. They usually spend all their time %s.") % input("Please enter a name: "), input("Please enter an adjective: "), input("Please eneter an ing verb: ")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2):

You misplaced your parenthesis. If you have more than one `%` formatted item in the string, you must wrap the arguments in parenthesis (a tuple).

```
print("%s is a very %s person. They usually spend all their time %s." % (input("Please enter a name: "), input("Please enter an adjective: "), input("Please eneter an ing verb: ")))
```

That is a functioning version. Make sure you take the time to understand the parenthesis used.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python2 then use raw_input() instead of input()

```
print("{0} is a very {1} person. They usually spend all their time {2}.".format(input("Please enter a name: "), input("Please enter an adjective: "), input("Please eneter an ing verb: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Split your line of code up into smaller pieces, see which one throws an error, and go from there.

The error is telling you it can't deal with a modulo operation between `None` and a `str` object.

Make sure you are dealing with strings all the way through before using modulo.